# Linux - Aspire 3 with Archlinux

Tags: linux

My wifi stop working. Was working O.K before.
My laptop is using this wireless card
lspci -k
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
In order to resolve this issue I installed the LTS Kernel instead of the regular one.
Now my laptop is using :

$ uname -r
4.19.101-1-lts
My wifi is working O.K again but then I found this problem that I don’t know how to resolve and I need help!!
My computer doesn't power off when I try to shutdown or reboot it, I'm forced to press the power button.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was resolved when the kernel was upgrade to 
uname -r
5.4.19-1-lts

Comment: Thanks for the update, a kernel update really improved things for me on Debian 10 with this card (with ASRock mini-itx motherboard)